# tmux copy last shell command to copy buffer

Tags: tmux

I am trying to create a binding so that `tmux` copies last executed command to its copy buffer.

I tried following key bindings but it does not work. What happens when I press `F5` is as follows:

1. tmux shows copy mode *without moving up*
2. I have to press q to exit copy mode
3. tmux then sends the key up, so shell shows last execute command
4. tmux's copy buffer has just newline

   `bind-key -n F5 send-keys Up \; send-keys C-a \; copy-mode \; send-keys -X begin-selection \; send-keys -X begin-selection \; send-keys -X end-of-line \; send-keys -X copy-selection`

I am using `tmux 2.5` and connected to a server from which I connect to different servers in different tmux windows.

Essentially I want to execute the command on all windows by copying the last command in copy buffer and then pasting it different windows for replicating.

Comment: A was trying to use vim, history, xclip, but without satisfying results. Finally I give up with this combination: press "arrow up", press "home", type: "echo '", press "end", type "' | xclip", press "enter". I have alias xclip="xclip -selection c". I hope There will occur better answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not answer about "copy last shell command", but it answers for your essential aim.

If you want to execute the command on all windows, then there is simplest solution:

Press:

```
Ctrl + a or Ctrl + b
```

And type:

```
:setw synchronize-panes
```

[image]

If you want to stop synchronization use command:

```
:setw synchronize-panes off
```

Sources

> https://gist.github.com/andreyvit/2921703
>
> https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/sync-tmux-panes/